# Waiting for copy thread to read lsn (Mariabackup infinite, loop, innodb)

Tags: mysql, linux, loops, mariadb, innodb

I have a problem only in remote backups (local backups run perfectly!)

I search information about this and i dont find much information or solutions!

There are no problems when the remote backup starts, until the infinite loop arrives !

I use Debian 11 and the mysql version is this:

`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.15-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`

I run this script for remote backup in my machine to the other machine (i use vitualbox for testing):

`mariabackup --backup --host=10.0.0.158 --port=3306 --target-dir=/home/martinezta/mariabackup/backup_remoto1 --user=root --password=P@ssw0rd`

[image: Beggining]

[image: The infinite Loop]

I stopped because its infinite...

**Configuration**

[MYSQL / MARIADB]

`mysql -u root –password=P@ssw0rd

CREATE USER root@10.0.0.215 IDENTIFIED BY ‘P@ssw0rd’ ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * .* TO root@10.0.0.215;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;`

`nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf/  [or]  nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

port = 3306`

`nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

#### testing configuration

I try with this configuration, and more combinations, i can't resolve my problem with this :(

`nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

`[mysqld]

innodb_io_capacity      = 3000

innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 3G

innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 3

innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT

## Logs

log-error           = /var/log/mysql/error.log

slow_query_log          = 1

slow_query_log_file     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

long_query_time         = 5`

##### MYSQL ENGINE INNODB STATUS

`Show engine innodb srtatus;`

[image: LOG]

If anyone can resolve my problem, thanks!

Comment: Please do not post images with code or logging autpout. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: How "far" away is the "remote" server?  That is what is the ping time.  (Or how long does `SELECT 1;` take.)

Comment: Did you get solution for this. Even iam seeing backup getting stuck with below message
[01] 2023-01-15 14:43:12 Compressing and streaming ./aria_log.00000001 to [01] 2023-01-15 14:43:12 ...done [00] 2023-01-15 14:43:12 Waiting for log copy thread to read lsn